# How to solve z fighting and transparency? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

The same as this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64593/z-fighting-despite-invisibility) probably.

Here is the setting:

- Two cubes which overlap (so, I know, they are "z fighting")
- One cube with diffuse
- The second with transparency

I was expecting the transparency won't be mixed here, but to see only the blue cube, because a transparent object should stay transparent (?).

Is it possible to avoid that without changing the cubes' positions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No I don't think it is, the solution is really not to have overlapping geometry, no render engine likes that really, and most deal with it pretty badly as far as I know, unless both objects have exactly the same material. Why would you want overlapping geometry in the first place, if I may ask?

Comment: Thanks for this comment, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I don't want overlapping geometry, but I'd like 'overlapping geometry safe' solution for this issue.

Comment: Only workaround I really know is that if both objects use a similar shader or material color the Z Fighting becomes less visible or unnoticeable

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, could you elaborate more this last comment? FYI, each cube here has its own material... so how can be understood 'similar shader'?

Comment: Nothing too elaborate, just mentioning that if both cubes were blue colored then you can't really see the Z fighting between them.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, sorry but I don't understand your comment. One cube is transparent (transparent shader), the other one is blue (diffuse shader). Could you explain what you meant?

Comment: If both cubes were to use the Blue material, instead of one being blue and one being transparent then you would never see any Z fighting, but of course it might defeat the purpose because both become actually visible.