# How to make a nanotech effect?

Tags: effects

I'm working on a short Iron man fan film, and I need to do a nanotech effect, I tried using the unfold add-on but it kept crashing, probably because the model is a full iron man suit, is there another way I can do a nanotech-type effect

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74987/how-to-animate-a-superhero-zap-into-his-super-suit-in-blender

Comment: By coincidence I've just seen this video recommended on YouTube, might be what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdE0zuLR1gY

Comment: thank you so much, I have been looking for a video like this!